# Могу ли я в SOAP выбрать тег ,где значение тега =?

Tags: php, curl, soap, php-curl

Можно ли в результате запроса SOAP api(с использованием php и curl), выбрать тег ,где значение тега = ?(Например в этом случае ,где CityName = BAKU).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <soap-env:Header xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <ns2:GetCitiesByCountryIdResponse xmlns:ns2="http://epg.generic.masterdata/">
            <ns2:CitiesByCountryIdResponse>
                <ns2:Cities>
                    <ns2:City>
                        <ns2:Cityid>156910</ns2:Cityid>
                        <ns2:CityName>ABSHERON</ns2:CityName>
                    </ns2:City>
                    <ns2:City>
                        <ns2:Cityid>156911</ns2:Cityid>
                        <ns2:CityName>BAKU</ns2:CityName>
                    </ns2:City>


      <ns2:City>
                    <ns2:Cityid>156912</ns2:Cityid>
                    <ns2:CityName>GYANDJA</ns2:CityName>
                </ns2:City>
                <ns2:City>
                    <ns2:Cityid>156913</ns2:Cityid>
                    <ns2:CityName>NAKHCHIVAN</ns2:CityName>
                </ns2:City>
                <ns2:City>
                    <ns2:Cityid>156914</ns2:Cityid>
                    <ns2:CityName>SUMGAIT</ns2:CityName>
                </ns2:City>
            </ns2:Cities>
        </ns2:CitiesByCountryIdResponse>
    </ns2:GetCitiesByCountryIdResponse>
</Body>
```

Comment: https://sitear.ru/material/php-parsing-html-simple-html-dom

Comment: Для этого проще сгенерировать классы по WSDL сервиса, и уже по ним делать пробежку и поиск нужного вам элемента. (https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/. Либо как прокомментировали выше, парсингом XML и запросом через XPath. (более трудоемко)